# how do you blit text to screen using classes in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to blit text onto a screen, but only using classes. When I create an instance from a class, is there any way to reference that same instance within the class? For example, in my code:

```
class _text_():
    def __init__(self, font, size, text, antialias, colour, background):
        self.font = font
        self.size = size
        self.text = text
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.colour = colour
        self.background = background 
    def _textsettings_(self):
        texts = pygame.font.SysFont(self.font, self.size)
        return texts.render(self.text, self.antialias, self.colour, self.background)
    def _textblit_(self):
        return win.blit[text1, (400, 240)]

text1 = _text_('calibri', 20, "press any button to start", True, black, None)
```

in the textblit function, I am trying to use variable 'text1' so that I can blit it to screen, but obviously this isn't working and I am stumped as to how to do it.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text surface becomes an instance attribute of the class (`self.text`):

```py
class _text_():
    def __init__(self, font, size, text, antialias, colour, background):
        self.font = font
        self.size = size
        self.text = text
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.colour = colour
        self.background = background 
        texts = pygame.font.SysFont(self.font, self.size)
        self.text = texts.render(self.text, self.antialias, self.colour, self.background)
    def _textblit_(self):
        win.blit(self.text, (400, 240))
```

Call `_textblit_` in the main application loop:

```
text1 = _text_('calibri', 20, "press any button to start", True, black, None)  

while True:

    # [...]

    text1._textblit_()

    # [...]
```

Comment: Oh, I had no idea you could do that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is the class :
name file = text.py

```py
import pygame
class _text_():
    def __init__(self,text):
        pygame.init()
        self.text = text
        self.antialias = True
        self.colour = (255,255,255)    
        self.background = None
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("arialblack",40)
        self.img = self.font.render(self.text, self.antialias, self.colour,self.background)
    def _textblit_(self,surface):
        surface.blit(self.img,(400,240))
```

This is the test

```py
import pygame
from text import _text_
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1200

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT))
text1 = _text_(": )")  

run = True

while run:
    screen.fill((52,78,91))
    text1._textblit_(screen)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    pygame.display.update()
    
pygame.quit()
```